# How to write data to array in firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase

How to write data to an array in Firebase?

I could upload multiple images to Firestore, but I need to write the data to `postImages` array.

I tried to use the below methods, but it didn't work and the app is crashing.

```
String postid = _firestore.collection('Posts').doc().id;
    await _firestore.collection('Posts').doc(postid).set({
      'description': description,
      'imageType': 'image',
      'location': getSub,
      'postImages': [],
      'postid': postid,
      'postimage': '',
      'profile_image': profImage,
      'publisher': uid,
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < _images.length; i++) {
      var imageUrl = uploadMultiImageToStroage('Posts', _images[i], true);
      _arrImageUrl.add(imageUrl.toString());
      await _firestore.collection('Posts').doc(postid).update({
        'postImages': FieldValue.arrayUnion([_arrImageUrl]),
      });
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide full error logs?

Comment: no error, the device just show me  `Null check operator used on a null value`

Comment: Please check first current usr exist of not then do the operation.
if (_auth.currentUser != null) {}

Comment: @ChiragKalsariya I'd update and rewrite the question, could you check please?

Comment: Might be this will help you, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fy-rCZVcw78

Comment: @ChiragKalsariya I'd saw that's video before, but I need to used for loop to updated data

Comment: The question states the *"the app is crashing"* but you didn't indicate what line was crashing but then your comment above states there's no error. So... is it crashing or not and if so, on what line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload all file first then update the database.

```
await Future.forEach(_images, (XFile image) async {
    var imageUrl = await uploadMultiImageToStroage('Posts', image, true);
    _arrImageUrl.add(imageUrl.toString());
});

await _firestore.collection('Posts').doc(postid).update({
    'postImages': FieldValue.arrayUnion([_arrImageUrl]),
  });
```

Comment: I tried to use this `await Future.forEach(_images, (XFile image) async {
        var imageUrl = await uploadMultiImageToStroage('Posts', image, true);
        _arrImageUrl.add(imageUrl.toString());
      });
      await _firestore.collection('Posts').doc(postid).update({
        'postImages': FieldValue.arrayUnion([_arrImageUrl]),
      });`

but still not update the postImages, it get the null array

Comment: fix this `await Future.forEach(_images, (XFile image) async {
        var imageUrl = await uploadMultiImageToStroage('Posts', image, true);
        _arrImageUrl.add(imageUrl.toString());
      });

      await _firestore.collection('Posts').doc(postid).update({
        'postImages': FieldValue.arrayUnion(_arrImageUrl),
      });`